# UITableview have bottom space when scrolled on iPhone x

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

UITableview have bottom space when scrolled on iPhone x. I have used storyboard and attached screenshot for the same.

[image: The constraints screenshot]

[image: The constraints screenshot]

Comment: The screenshots don't seem to be attached.

Comment: sorry i did it now

Comment: That's the safe area, like it's suppose to be. But if you don't want it for whatever reason, simply attach the bottom constraint of the table to the superview, not the safe area.

Comment: i have already added it to the superview

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need that bottom padding then make sure your bottom constraint is to the superview, rather than the safe area.